Azure Data Explorer (ADX) Associated Blob Stores
This is a follow-on from this previous question:
When working with ADX, I've encountered Blob Client errors in two scenarios:

When trying to read data from ADX into Databricks Spark
Dataframe using pyspark with the spark Kusto connector for ADX
(com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource).
(2) When trying to ingest data from an Azure Windows VM running a
python client with azure-kusto-ingest library.

The problem in both cases seem to be related to networking, where both of these clients can connect to ADX with no problem, with ADX being on a private endpoint, but they cannot connect to certain blob stores.  It seems that maybe these blob stores are associated with ADX, and the ADX Kusto API is directing the client to directly connect to these blob stores.
These blob stores happen to be named like the following, and they do not seem to be on the same private endpoint as our ADX cluster:

0uz{adx_cluster_name}01
j6v{adx_cluster_name}00

I'm having trouble finding any ADX documentation explaining what is going on with these blob stores or where they come from.
Question: Where do these storage accounts / blob stores come from?  Are they part of the ADX configuration and can they be changed so that they are on the same private endpoint as our ADX cluster, or could we replace them with existing storage accounts that we already have on our private endpoint?

The issue with the Blob Client errors in the two scenarios mentioned may be related to networking, as the clients can connect to ADX but not to certain blob stores. It is recommended to check the network configuration and ensure that the clients have the necessary permissions to access the blob stores.
